# Quantidade de páginas impressas com window.print()

Tags: javascript

O relatório em que estou trabalhando contém tabelas e gráficos, que na tela estão sendo exibidos normalmente. Porém ao imprimir o relatório com a função `window.print()`, o relatório não está sendo apresentado por completo, o pdf gerado está cortando o conteúdo após a quinta página.

Alguém sabe me informar se há alguma limitação quanto à quantidade de páginas impressas?

Comment: Creio que o problema não seja JavaScript, uma vez que a impressão tem mais a ver com o HTML (o código pode aparecer corretamente no navegador mas na janela de impressão aparecer errado) ou com a configuração da impressão (tamanho do papel, orientação da folha, margens etc). Seria interessante, para melhor análise, vc postar na pergunta um print da parte de como aparece correto e de como aparece errado na impressão.

Comment: Não há limite para página impressa. É importante adaptar o seu estilo com media @print para que ele seja impresso corretamente. Qual é a forma de você usa para gerar o PDF?

Comment: Consegui resolver imprimindo o conteúdo em formato paisagem.

Comment: Se puder postar uma breve resposta e depois marcar como "resposta certa", seria muito bom para evitar que a sua pergunta fique "abandonada" como "sem resposta" e que também possa ajudar outras pessoas que venham a ter problema parecido. Abs!